# laravel 4 - how to Limit (Take and Skip) for Eloquent ORM?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, limit, eloquent

### TL;DR

Can you limit an Eloquent ORM query like using `take()` and `skip()` so that the resulting mysql query is also limited, and it doesn't have to return the entire dataset?

If so, how would you modify:

```
$test = User::find(1)->games->toArray();
```

To include `limit 3 offset 2`?

---

### Tables:

```
users       games           userGames
-- id       -- id           -- user_id
-- name     -- name         -- game_id
            -- steam_id
```

### Models:

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    public function games() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game', 'userGames', 'user_id', 'game_id');
    }
}

class Game extends Eloquent {
    public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'userGames', 'user_id', 'game_id');
    }
}
```

---

### Limit in Query Builder

Using the regular Laravel **Query Builder** I can get all `games` that belong to `user` of id 1, and limit the result with `take()` and `skip()`:

```
$test = DB::table('games')
    ->join('userGames', 'userGames.game_id', '=', 'games.id')
    ->where('userGames.user_id', '=', '1')->take(3)->skip(2)->get();
```

By listening to the `illuminate.query` event I can see that the query generated by this is:

```
select * from `games`
inner join `userGames`
on `userGames`.`game_id` = `games`.`id`
where `userGames`.`user_id` = ?
limit 3 offset 2
```

### Limit in Eloquent ORM

When I try to recreate the same query with Eloquent:

```
$test = User::find(1)->games->take(2)->toArray();
```

I'm able to use `take` but adding `skip` causes an error. Also the resulting query does not actually contain the limit:

```
select `games`.*, `userGames`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`,
`userGames`.`game_id` as `pivot_game_id` from `games`
inner join `userGames`
on `games`.`id` = `userGames`.`game_id`
where `userGames`.`user_id` = ?
```

So it seems that the entire result is being queried first, which is not ideal when dealing with large data sets.

---

### Question:

Is it possible to limit an Eloquent ORM query so that at the MYSQL Query level it also limits the result, equivalent to `limit 3 offset 2`?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
User::find(1)->games()->take(3)->skip(2)->get();
```

I think this should give you your collection. :)

`->games` will give you a collection, where `->games()` will offer a query builder instance.

Enjoy Laravel!

Comment: Hey, how might I count the number of rows that were found before taking and skipping? Only way i can see at present is by duplicating the query. cheers