# Laravel Eloquent nested query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I was working with Laravel and got stuck in a situation. I have following models:

- Category
- Product
- CategoryProduct

`CategoryProduct` holds the information about which product belongs to which category (a product may belong to multiple categories).

Now, when I want to load all products belonging to a particular category, I need to run query on `Product` and `CategoryProduct`  which is where I'm stuck.

I gave it the following try but was unsuccessful:

```
$products = Product::where('status', '=', 'active')
->where('category_id', '=', $category_id)
->take($count)
->skip($skip)
->get();
```

Obviously, it will say that `category_id` is not a column.

Here is my DB & Model structure:

### **categories table**

id,
name,
etc.

### **products table**

id, 
name,
sku,
etc.

### **category_products table**

id,
product_id,       ( Foreign key to Product.id )
category_id,      ( Foreign key to Category.id )
etc.

### **Product model**

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'products';

protected $hidden = array();

    public static $rules = array('name' => 'required|min:3');

}
```

**Category model**

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'categories';

public static $rules = array('name' => 'required|min:3');

}
```

**CategoryProduct model**

```
<?php

class CategoryProduct extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'category_products';

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Product');
}

public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
}
```

## **Update**

**A new question on this**

I'm trying to display products. If category is not passed (value is -1), then I will show all products, otherwise I will show products from the passed category.

Now, when I show all products, those products may already exist in a category. I want to display ticked checkbox for products that are already in a category. I'm doing something like this:

```
if($category_id==-1)
        $products = Product::where('status', '=', 'active')->take($count)->skip($skip)->get();
    else{
        $products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($category_id)
        {
            $q->where('category_id', $category_id);
        })->where('status', 'active')
            ->take($count)
            ->skip($skip)
            ->get();
    }
```

The table **category_products** have product_id, category_id as columns.

Now, the query:

$products = Product::where('status', '=', 'active')->take($count)->skip($skip)->get();

will pick products only from **products** table. If I check each product for its existence in **category_products**, then there will be too many database queries for large number of products.

Any idea, how to achieve this. I hope I was able to clear my situation. Thanks

Comment: Look into the `has`/`whereHas` functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CategoryProduct` model should not be necessary unless you have additional fields besides product_id and category_id which point to other relationships.

What is necessary are the methods for setting up the relationship on the `Category` and `Product` models.

In `Category`, add the relationship function...

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'category_products');
}
```

In your `Product` model, do the same for categories.

```php
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'category_products');
}
```

Then you can query for your active products that belong to that category using your relationship method and `whereHas()`

```php
$products = Product::whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($category_id)
{
    $q->where('id', $category_id);
})->where('status', 'active')
->take($count)
->skip($skip)
->get();
```

Comment: Hey user3158900 thanks for the quick reply. CategoryProduct is used because a product may belong to multiple category.

Comment: @Ashutosh Many-to-many pivot tables don't require a model. Take a look at the documentation link in my answer

Comment: Ok, got it what you wanted to say, thanks again. Looking at the documentation now.

Comment: When you use `belongsToMany` on the parent tables, Laravel will handle and manage the pivot table (`category_prodcuts`) for you.  The only thing you need to do is tell Laravel what the name of that table is, which I have edited/added in my answer.

Comment: @user1669496 hi, but what if the product owned by a vendor? instead of `$product = Products::whereHas()` but `$vendor = Vendors::whereHas()`. Vendor is the parent of the Products. How is this possible to use the condition under multiple nested relations?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a model for a pivot table in Many-to-Many relationships. Look at [this section](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many) of the Eloquent documentation for further explanation.

You still need to create a migration to set up the pivot table (or do it manually if you don't use migrations), but not a model. Instead, create a function for `Category` to designate the relationship:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'category_products');
    // - You might need to adjust the namespace of App\Product
    // - category_products refers to the pivot table name
}
```

Likewise, `Product` needs a similar public function.

Then you're able to do it the other way around, by finding the category and then listing all its related products:

```
$products = Category::find($category_id)
   ->products()
   ->where('status', 'active')
   ->take($count)
   ->skip($skip)
   ->get();
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204342/laravel-4-how-to-limit-take-and-skip-for-eloquent-orm) could also be relevant to yours.