# Nested select using laravel query builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, builder

I'm trying to find a way convert it to query builder in laravel but I still can't do it!!

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT thanhvientrong.manguoidung, detai.ngaykt, COUNT(*)
    AS c FROM detai
    INNER JOIN thanhvientrong ON detai.madt = thanhvientrong.madt AND detai.id_cap = 5
    GROUP BY thanhvientrong.manguoidung HAVING c > 0
  )
  AS dem where DATE(ngaykt) BETWEEN '2019-09-14' AND '2020-09-15'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm not really catch what you mean.
But, i think these solutions will help you:

- [Laravel Eloquent nested query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29751104/laravel-eloquent-nested-query)
- https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-nested-query-builder?page=1

I think relationship will be the best solution for your issue.